# Was Professor Huyang transported in The TARDIS?

Tags: star-wars, doctor-who, tardis

On page 68 of Star Wars canon adult novel *Brotherhood* by Mike Chen (2022), Professor Huyang is referenced as being so old that the ancient droid purportedly arrived at the Jedi Temple in a big blue box thousands of years ago before ever taught lightsaber creation. Here a snapshot of the passage:

[image: Passage on page 68 of novel Brotherhood by Mike Chen]

The aforementioned blue box is reminiscent of The TARDIS, the ship from Doctor Who. An improbable blue box that can move in space and time and is larger on the inside than the outside. The TARDIS resembles a large blue police box from the 1960s. That is why I inquire whether Professor Huyang could have been transferred in The TARDIS.

Comment: I wouldn't describe the TARDIS as being huge, at least not from the outside...

Comment: It's just a funny reference to him being voiced by David Tennant or something.

Comment: In-universe, it's just a tall tale told by younglings at the temple. Out of universe; it's just a gag reference to Tennant playing The Doctor. Either way, best not to take it too seriously.

Comment: @bob1 - Bob1, I apologize. I mistranscribed the passage from the novel. It reads, "...big blue box." I just uploaded a screenshot of the novel's text. Regards.